# When the page closes, I want to initialize the ViewModel's value to null

Tags: wpf

When the page closes, I want to initialize the ViewModel's value to null.

I tried as below, but a runtime error occurs.

I ask for advice from people who have tried it.

Thank you very much.

Please help..

```
<Page x:Class="SampleMVVM.View.PersonView"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleMVVM.View" 
      xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:SampleMVVM.ViewModel"
      xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
      xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="PersonView">
    
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unloaded" >
            <!-- PropertyName 'PersonViewModel' Not Found (Runtime Error occur)-->
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="PersonViewModel" Value="{x:Null}" /> 
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    
    <Page.Resources>
        <!-- I want to this value to null -->
        <local1:PersonViewModel x:Key="PersonViewModel"/>  

        <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local1:PersonViewModel}" >
            <StackPanel Margin="50">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonModel.Name, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

                <TextBox  Text="{Binding PersonModel.Address, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

                <Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <StaticResource ResourceKey="PersonViewModel"/>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PersonViewModel` is the type, not the name of the Property.
You seem to be using `PersonModel` in your bindings

Answer (score 0):

Use DataContext, it works.

```
<Window x:Class="SampleMVVM.View.PersonView"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleMVVM.View" 
      xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:SampleMVVM.ViewModel"
      xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
      xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="PersonView">
    
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unloaded" >
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="DataContext" Value="{x:Null}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local1:PersonViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local1:PersonViewModel}" >
            <StackPanel Margin="50">
                <Label Content="Name"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonModel.Name, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

                <Label Content="Address"/>
                <TextBox  Text="{Binding PersonModel.Address, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

                <Label Content="Save to DB then Clear" Height="50" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"/>
                <Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <local1:PersonViewModel />
</Window>
```